# Docker how to ADD a file without committing it to an image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a ~300Mb zipped local file that I add to a docker image.  The next state then extracts the image.

The problem is that the ADD statement results in a commit that results in a new file system layer makes the image ~300Mb larger than it needs to be.

```
ADD /files/apache-stratos.zip /opt/apache-stratos.zip
RUN unzip -q apache-stratos.zip && \
    rm apache-stratos.zip && \
    mv apache-stratos-* apache-stratos
```

**Question**: Is there a work-around to ADD local files without causing a commit?

One option is to run a simple web server (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`) before starting the docker build, and then using `wget` to retrieve the file, but that seems a bit messy:

```
RUN wget http://localhost:8000/apache-stratos.zip && \
    unzip -q apache-stratos.zip && \
    rm apache-stratos.zip && \
    mv apache-stratos-* apache-stratos
```

Another option is to extract the zipped file at container start up instead of build time, but I would prefer to keep the start up as quick as possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add), if you pass an archive file from the local filesystem (not a URL) to ADD in the Dockerfile (with a destination path, not a path + filename), it will uncompress the file into the directory given.

> If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format
>   (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.
>   Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed. When a directory is
>   copied or unpacked, it has the same behavior as tar -x: the result is
>   the union of:
>
> 1) Whatever existed at the destination path and 2) The contents of the 
>   source tree, with conflicts resolved in favor of "2." on a file-by-file basis.

try:

```
ADD /files/apache-stratos.zip /opt/
```

and see if the files are there, without further decompression.

Comment: It seems does not decompress `.zip` file on Docker 1.2.0.

Comment: "If [src] is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory."

Comment: The fact of ADD lacking support for `.zip` files seems to be an intended decision: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15036

Comment: *This answer does not actually work* ``ADD /files/apache-stratos.zip /opt/``  makes a file called ``/opt/apache-stratos.zip``

Answer (score 5):

With Docker 17.05+ you can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to avoid creating extra layers.

```
FROM ... as stage1
# No need to clean up here, these layers will be discarded
ADD /files/apache-stratos.zip /opt/apache-stratos.zip
RUN unzip -q apache-stratos.zip
    && mv apache-stratos-* apache-stratos

FROM ...
COPY --from=stage1 apache-stratos/ apache-stratos/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [docker-squash](https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash) to squash newly created layers. That should reduce the image size significantly.

Unfortunately the mentioned workarounds (`RUN curl ... && unzip ... & rm ...`, unpack on container start) are the only options at the moment (docker 1.11).

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 3 options I can think of.

---

Option 1: you can switch to a tar or compressed tar format from the zip file and then allow `ADD` to decompress the file for you.

```
ADD /files/apache-stratos.tgz /opt/
```

Only downside is any other changes, like a directory rename, will trigger the copy on write again, so you need to make sure your tar file has the contents in the final directory structure.

---

Option 2: Use a multi-stage build. Extract the file in an early stage, perform any changes, and then copy the resulting directory to your final stage. This is a good option for any build engines that cannot use BuildKit. [augurar's answer covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54896149/596285) so I won't repeat the same Dockerfile he already has.

---

Option 3: BuildKit (available in 18.09 and newer) allows you to mount files from other locations, including your build context, within a `RUN` command. This currently requires the experimental syntax. The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ...
...
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=/files/apache-stratos.zip,target=/opt/apache-stratos.zip \
    unzip -q apache-stratos.zip && \
    rm apache-stratos.zip && \
    mv apache-stratos-* apache-stratos
```

Then to build that, you export a variable before running your build (you could also export it in your .bashrc or equivalent):

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t your_image .
```

More details on BuildKit's experimental features are available here: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md