# How to add a file to an image in Dockerfile without using the ADD or COPY directive

Tags: docker

I need the contents of a large `*.zip` file (5 gb) in my `Docker` container in order to compile a program. The `*.zip` file resides on my local machine. The strategy for this would be:

```
COPY program.zip /tmp/
RUN cd /tmp \
&& unzip program.zip \
&& make
```

After having done this I would like to remove the unzipped directory and the original `*.zip` file because they are not needed any more. The problem is that the `COPY` (and also the `ADD` directive) will add a layer to the image that will contain the file `program.zip` which is problematic as may image will be at least 5gb big. Is there a way to add a file to a container without using `COPY` or `ADD` directive? `wget` will not work as the mentioned `*.zip` file is on my local machine and `curl file://localhost/home/user/program.zip -o /tmp/program.zip` will not work either.

Comment: Can't you simply unzip it beforehand on your local machine? And then add the stuff you need?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to delete the unzipped folder as it will still be over 5 gb. But I found a way how to do what I want. Answer is on it's way.

Comment: and a make.sh file that does the build and removes the file?

Comment: A layer with the `*.zip` will still be part of the image. Could you explain how a  shell script would help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not straightforward but it can be done via `wget` or `curl` with a little support from `python`. (All three tools should usually be available on a `*nix` system.)

`wget` will not work when no `url` is given and

```
 curl file://localhost/home/user/program.zip -o /tmp/
```

will not work from within a `Dockerfile`'s `RUN` instruction. Hence, we will need a server which `wget` and `curl` can access and download `program.zip` from.

To do this we set up a little `python` server which serves our `http` requests. We will be using the `http.server` module from `python` for this. (You can use `python` or `python 3`. It will work with both.).

```
python -m http.server --bind 192.168.178.20 8000
```

The `python` server will serve all files in the directory it is started in. So you should make sure that you start your server either in the directory the file you want to download during your image build resides in or create a temporary directory which contains your program. For illustration purposes let's create the file `foo.txt` which we will later download via `wget` in our `Dockerfile`:

```
echo "foo bar" > foo.txt
```

When starting the http server, it is important, that we specify the IP address of our local machine on the LAN. Furthermore, we will open Port 8000. Having done this we should see the following output:

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 192.168.178.20 8000
Serving HTTP on 192.168.178.20 port 8000 ...
```

Now we build a `Dockerfile` to illustrate how this works. (We will assume that the file `foo.txt` should be downloaded into `/tmp`):

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -y wget
RUN cd /tmp \
&& wget http://192.168.178.20:8000/foo.txt
```

Now we start the build with

```
docker build -t test .
```

During the build you will see the following output on our `python` server:

```
172.17.0.21 - - [01/Nov/2014 23:32:37] "GET /foo.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and the build output of our image will be:

```
Step 2 : RUN cd /tmp && wget http://192.168.178.20:8000/foo.txt
 ---> Running in 49c10e0057d5
--2014-11-01 22:56:15--  http://192.168.178.20:8000/foo.txt
Connecting to 192.168.178.20:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 25872 (25K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `foo.txt'

     0K .......... .......... .....                           100%  129M=0s

2014-11-01 22:56:15 (129 MB/s) - `foo.txt' saved [25872/25872]

 ---> 5228517c8641
Removing intermediate container 49c10e0057d5
Successfully built 5228517c8641
```

You can then check if it really worked by starting and entering a container from the image you just build:

```
docker run -i -t --rm test bash
```

You can then look in `/tmp` for `foo.txt`.

We can now add any file to our `image` without creating an new layer. Assuming you want to add a program of about 5 gb as mentioned in the question we could do:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -y wget
RUN cd /tmp \
&& wget http://conventiont:8000/program.zip \
&& unzip program.zip \
&& cd program \
&& make \
&& make install \
&& cd /tmp \
&& rm -f program.zip \
&& rm -rf program
```

In this way we will not be left with 10 gb of cruft.

Comment: Clever! Need to host this on something like aws though if you want to do a trusted build.

Comment: This approach is great, but it does require the host to have a stable IP, otherwise you need to keep changing the IP address used in the wget in the guest. Would be nice to have a solution to address that too (I haven't had any good ideas yet!).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this.  A feature request is here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3156.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not map a local folder to the container when launched and then copy the files you need.

```
sudo docker run -d -P --name myContainerName -v /localpath/zip_extract:/container/path/ yourContainerID
```

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: I probably would have to unzip and compile the program every time the container starts (Or do it at least once when the container starts and then commit it.). I wanted a single `Dockerfile` based solution.

Comment: Ah, having read your answer, i now see what you were trying to do. Nice solution.

Comment: volume mapping can only be done during "run" not during "build". When adding volumes on build some tools (including vagrant) auto-add/copy. You don't want this as each extra-instructions will be compiled to a deltay layer in the final docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542913/909579

You can use [docker-squash](https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash) to squash newly created layers. That will essentially remove the archive from final image if you remove it in subsequent `RUN` instruction.